# Create 3 Level Relations with ACF and Wordpress

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, advanced-custom-fields

i have a more or less huge project and i decided to use wordpress.

I want to create a nutrition plan. Therefore i use custom post types for recipes and advanced custom fields vor values like kcal and so on.

The user can create nutrition plans and there he can add some recipes, so i need to build a relationship from user > nutrition plans > recipes and at the moment i dont have any ideas how to solve this problem with wordpress and acf.

At the moment i have a array with the id's of the recipes and want to save them intro a nutrition plan.

Do you guys have any ideas to build this up? Thanks for help :)

Comment: Would saving Post IDs as [User Meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta) work for you?

Comment: You need to define your relationships first. Can one user have  many nutrition plans? Can one nutrition plan have many recipes? Can one recipes belong to any number of nutrition plans? or only to one?

Comment: Oh ok, so 1 user can have many (maybe up to 5) nutrition plans and one nutrition plan can also have many recipes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "Nutrition plan" post type should use the Repeater Field from ACF: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/repeater-field/

Inside this Repeater Field you have to use "Post Object" filtering only your "Recipes" post type: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/post-object/

Comment: I think that the only problem with this, is that one user will be able to see/use recipes posted by other users.